# Inline styling in React functional component for #root element

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar, react-functional-component

I have created a React functional component where I have attached an event listener for scrolling. I have observed that this event listener needs to be attached to the element with ID = "root" i.e something of this sort - `document.getElementById("root")`. Currently, I have a seperate CSS file to apply the styling to my component specifically for the scrollbar. The CSS stylesheet has a single class `#root` where I provide `overflow-y: scroll`, so that scrolling happens properly.
But now, I wish to get this styling within my React functional component. How can this be done ?